# What test should I use to compare multiple response answers (a check all that apply question) by age group?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons

I am writing my dissertation and have gathered data from a database regarding societal attitudes and lifestyle choices based on different age groups.

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6Mn8.png)

The attached table is an example of an answer to one of the questions asking about activities one likes to do in their free time at home. Respondents were asked to check all that apply.

I would like to test if there were any differences in the number of respondents for each category. As you can see, my sample sizes are different.

Which test would I use to go about doing this? I have also calculated the proportions of each (see below). Should I be calculating based off of these values instead?

[image]

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the classical scenario of a $\chi^2$-Test of homogeneity. This test has the null hypothesis that all categories have the same distribution of the other categorical variable which is more or less what you are asking.

Any standard statistical software can handle this.